# Source function does not work - Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to create my DashboardBody() in different script but it gives me an error. I have saved all my workings that are related to Dashboard body in Dashboard_body.R script and I call this script in my main app

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard Basic"),
  
  dashboardSidebar(),
  
  source("Dashboard_body.R", local = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

```
dashboardBody(
  # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
  fluidRow(
    box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
    
    box(
      title = "Controls",
      sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
    )
  )
)
```

```
Error in tagAssert(body, type = "div", class = "content-wrapper") : 
  Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'.
```

Answer (score 3):

The `source()` function will return a list with the last value and whether or not is was visible. To access the value, you can do

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard Basic"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  source("Dashboard_body.R", local = TRUE)$value
)
```

But really, if you are sourcing a file it's better to keep proper functions in there. That makes it much easier to reuse.

So have something like

```
get_body <- function() {
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
      box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Then you would source before creating the UI and call your function

```
source("Dashboard_body.R")
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard Basic"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  get_body()
)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your help and for your tips!